# How to design an efficient high power bilateral switch for this special purpose?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, analog, power-electronics, switching

I need to design a system that equalizes the two capacitors on each side. There are two big capacitors in the system and they will be charging and discharging by out of the system. They might reach to 105V and down to GND at any time. We won't know that, I am only responsible for equalizing the capacitor voltages by an interrupt input.

The thing is, I can not consume much power, I have to be efficient. So selenoid and other inefficient switching solutions don't work here. I would use transmission gates(like in the figure below) to do it if capacitor potentials were not allowed to exceed 20V (Due to \$V_{GS}\$ limitations) but it is not a fit for this system either. So, is there any energy efficient method to allow bilateral current transmission? (In OPEN State there will be no current flow, in CLOSED State Current will flow from high potential to the lower potential)

Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNlHgR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is "efficient" for the purpose of your question? What is "unilateral current transmission" (does your circuit miss a diode, or do you mean something else)? What is "solenoind kinda stuff"?

Comment: I thought I understood what you were asking until the last sentence.  I can't even guess what *"in OPEN state there will be one current through it"* is supposed to convey.  One current as apposed to what?  Do you somehow expect two currents in the closed state?  How can there be any current if the switch is open? We do engineering here, not hand waving.  Closing this mess.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Apologies, that was a bad mistake. I corrected it "in OPEN state there will be no current flow"

Comment: If one cap is at 105 V and the other is at zero, you will be dumping a few joules into the switch every time you "equalize". It certainly won't be efficient or good for the switches. Also, "not allowed to exceed 5V (Due to Vgs limitations)" makes little sense. Not only do most power MOSFETs have a Vgs rating of +/-20 V or better, high side gate drivers are a thing. The way you have connected those MOSFETs also makes no sense. Why would you put a P-channel and N-channel in parallel? Are you aware that their body diodes will allow current to flow freely from c3 to c4?

Comment: I owe an apology to everybody who tried to understand this Question for its first 10 minutes. I made lots of mistakes, I may have emphasized lots of terms (like bilateral) unnecessarily. But I believe I corrected the Question now. And I really need to find a solution this is the last puzzle of the system, I have been working on this for like 3 months. I did not mean to annoy anybody but I must be inherently good at it. Sorry for that.

Comment: @jms has pointed out a major flaw of the transmission-gate topology (body diodes!), and you have also pointed out the Vgs(max) limitation. Your requirement for "efficiency" suggests that switch resistance should be near zero. This will result in a **huge** current spike that can damage capacitors.

Comment: @Alper91 Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for help on writing good questions in the future, a rule of thumb is to try and create a post so no one would have to ask any questions to clarify it. Try and write for your audience.

Comment: @laptop2d you are absolutely right, i am re-reading it. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a novel suggestion coming on.

Note this is not a finished design, but a suggestion that you might like to consider, and finish designing if it offers some advantages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Zb1Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Key to its operation is the fact that power FETs have a body diode across the junction. I've shown these explicitly.

When the switch is off, Q1 is conducting, and the FET sources are at around 0v. C1 charges to nearly the supply voltage via D1. Q3 is off, so there is no voltage across the zener, the gate driver is configured to put 0v on the gates in this state, so the FETs are off. They withstand whatever (positive) voltage is present on the capacitors (not shown) connected to nodes 1 and 2.

When the switch is required to turn on, Q1 is turned off. Q3 is turned on, to enable the gate driver. When the FETs turn on, the FET connected to the higher voltage node will pull the sources up. The body diode of the other FET will send current to the lower voltage node. The transistors used for Q1 and Q3 must be able to tolerate the maximum capacitor voltage on their collectors.

D1 will reverse bias, isolating C1, which should be large enough to support the current required of the gate driver, and that through R4, for the duration of the on pulse. A CMOS gate driver need use very little power once the gate capacitances have charged.

R1 and R2 are to limit the potentially very large current that could flow if very different charge state capacitors are connected by low RSDon FETs.

Obviously Q3 R4 Zener could be replaced by an optoisolator quite easily.

This is efficient in the sense that a well designed gate driver need take very little power. It is not efficient in that the energy lost to the two capacitor system when the voltages are equalised (stored energy after equalisation will *always* be less than that before) is lost as heat in R1 and R2. A switch mode system would be required to equalise the capacitors with less (zero in the ideal case) energy loss.

You might recognise the configuration of a high side gate driver here. If you found one with suitable voltage rating, that would integrate the gate driver and the level shifter for you, but you would probably still need an external C1, D1 and Q1.

Answer (score 0):

Note that closing that switch will always cost you energy proportional to the difference in the squares of the capacitor voltages... This is down to physics, and it will appear as a mixture of EM and heat. 
It is interesting to note that adding series resistance makes the equalisation slower but does NOT change the total energy cost).

The way to do this efficiently is a 4 switch buck/boost converter (which can run power in either direction) together with some control logic.

How about a couple of P channel mosfets connected drain to drain in series with the gates pulled low for on (Zenner diode clamp to ensure Vgs limit is not exceeded).

Personally I think you have an XY problem here, why do you think you need this thing?